# Nested ifelse statement with multiple selection criteria

Tags: r, if-statement

| YDST | Year |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020 |
| 1 | 2020 |
| 2 | 2020 |
| 3 | 2020 |
| 4 | 2020 |
| 5 | 2020 |
| 6 | 2020 |
| 7 | 2020 |
| 8 | 2020 |
| 9 | 2020 |
| 10 | 2020 |
| 0 | 2021 |
| 1 | 2021 |
| 2 | 2021 |
| 3 | 2021 |
| 4 | 2021 |
| 5 | 2021 |
| 6 | 2021 |
| 7 | 2021 |
| 8 | 2021 |
| 9 | 2021 |
| 10 | 2021 |

I have a data frame ('df') where I want to create a new column ('Students') where 'ns' indicates no students and 's' indicates students. However where 'ns' and 's' occur differs between years based on 'YDST'. For instance, in 2020 'ns' should be indicated from 0-3 and 9-10. In 2021, 'ns' should be indicated from '1-4', '6-7', and '9-10'.

How can I write a nested ifelse statement to not only account for 'Year', but also the different 'YDST' selection criteria between years?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ifelse` statement to check for the conditions and assign value `'ns'`   or `'s'`.

```
transform(df, students = ifelse(Year == 2020 & YDST %in% c(0:3, 9, 10) | 
                           Year == 2021 & YDST %in% c(1:4, 6:7, 9:10), 'ns','s'))

#   YDST Year students
#1     0 2020       ns
#2     1 2020       ns
#3     2 2020       ns
#4     3 2020       ns
#5     4 2020        s
#6     5 2020        s
#7     6 2020        s
#8     7 2020        s
#9     8 2020        s
#10    9 2020       ns
#11   10 2020       ns
#...
#...
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(YDST = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), Year = c(2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L)), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This was close. I couldn't quite get it to work as is, but modified it so this worked: df$student= ifelse(df$Year == 2020 & df$YDST %in% c(0:3, 9, 10) | 
                           df$Year == 2021 & df$YDST %in% c(1:4, 6:7, 9:10), 'ns','s'))

Thank you for getting me most of the way there!

Answer (score 0):

We can create a key/value dataset and do a join

```
library(dplyr)
keyval <- data.frame(Year = rep(c(2020, 2021), c(5, 8)) 
        val = c(0:3, 9:10, 1:4, 6:7, 9:10))
left_join(df, keyval) %>%
       mutate(Students = case_when(YDST %in% val ~ 'ns', TRUE ~ 's'), val = NULL)
```